# index out of bounds error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rgb, pixel, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to get the RGB values of a pixel of an image chosen by the user, but then I get this out of bounds error. This is the code:

```
x = int16(zeros(10,1));
y = int16(zeros(10,1));

imshow(img);
[x,y] = ginput; 
disp(['x = ' num2str(x)]);
disp(['y= ' num2str(y)]);
r = img(x,y,1);
g = img(x,y,2);
b = img(x,y,3);
```

And this is the error I get (when the user chooses the pixel 120,131):

*Attempted to access img(120,131,1);
index must be a positive integer or logical.*

To stop having this error I declared x and y as a int16, but the error still apeared. Then I tried to put the value of the pixel manually so I did something like this:

```
 r = img(229,104,1);
```

And the error now is this:

*Attempted to access img(229,104,1); index out of
bounds because size(img)=[217,331,3].*

How is this possible If the pixel isn't really out of bounds? What is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Shai's answer, I'm also wondering if the call to `ginput` doesn't overwrite the data type declared as `int16` for `x` and `y`? If I do something similar in Octave, I get:

```
>> [x,y]=ginput
x =  79.798
y =  72.042
```

I would suggest:

```
r = img(round(y),round(x),1);
g = img(round(y),round(x),2);
b = img(round(y),round(x),3);
```

Comment: Yeah It worked! But as you asked, the data type is not overwriten because the disp I put shows integer numbers... a bit strange, but well I will use your suggestion.

Comment: Try using the `precision` argument when calling `numstr`, I'm pretty confident you'll find they're not integer numbers. You can also check the data type with `whos`.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing X-Y coordinates with row-column coordinates.

`ginput` returs x ( = column ), y ( = row ) coordinates of a pixel.
When accessing the matrix `img( ?, ?, : )` you need to provide **row** ( = y ), **column** ( - x ) coordinates:

```
>> img( y, x, 1 )
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, but still having the **index must be a positive integer or logical.** error

Comment: @user2952272 See my answer, I suspect `ginput` returns double precision numbers.